# Why doesn't TypeScript use type narrowing for symbol properties?

Tags: typescript

TypeScript doesn't appear to narrow the types of symbol properties. For example:

```
const bar = Symbol('bar');

class Foo {
    [bar]: string | undefined;
    'baz': string | undefined;
}

function getBarLength(f: Foo) {
    if (f[bar] === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Expected bar to be defined');
    }
    return f[bar].length; // ERROR(2532): Object is possibly undefined
}

function getBazLength(f: Foo) {
    if (f['baz'] === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Expected baz to be defined');
    }
    return f['baz'].length; // No error
}
```

[In the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=20&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4wLwwMoE8C2cQA2AFAOSJIkCUA3AFC3AEIQQwBiIIMA3rTPzADa5ALoAuGNCQBLMAHMYAHxgBXMABMApgDNZm9XQEwyCAF4kJU2QuVqtusProBfetrXAo08DDmaoAELIADKa8lAAFkTaEhwglDx8AtLaMNHCyCJoqOh2OnrqCbxGRpFIIADuMI5VAKJI5UiktQAeAA6anvrwyDBQXHCaMPYFVIYCrkZI-ipIYDDaGUgiAHQEYXKR1DAA9DswtQBKhwDyh0QATACsAMwXlBIncABWnbDSrG0gLNJwBFiqDT5RzqWiuWjuMCebzzPyBMyhcJRGLsThFJL8FJpRYmcxZHK5IEOfTokoCMqVaqaOoNEBNEitDpddQ9Ux9AZDEYgsYYmCTATTKCzeY4xB4tYbLa7fYAOS4mlpSDBQA)

I am wondering if this is by design? If so, what's the reasoning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is a side-effect of how you have to use variables to retain the symbol value and thus have to use that variable to access the symbol property, rather than the property name directly, for instance it has a similarly hard time with string properties when using object property notation, even if the string is `const`:

```
const abc = 'abc' as const;

class Foo {
    [abc]: string | undefined;
}

function getAbcLength(f: Foo) {
    if (f[abc] === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Expected abc to be defined');
    }
    return f[abc].length; // ERROR(2532): Object is possibly undefined
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=12&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgI2DAvDA5I474RqSKAbgCgTgAbOCPAMRBBgG8SY2YBtLAXQC4ZoAJwCWYAOYwAPjACuYACYBTAGajF80gF8yyucCjDwMMYqgBBJABlF4qAAsAFMv70QASmat2w5TCdckblQUNDklVTB1DxZ2WJh7QRAAdxhIlIBRQUTBB3R0gA8AB0V9dXgkeMYERRhwtXl0N1JY7VjBUxlBMBhlAOBuADoKGzF7IhgAegmYdIAlWYB5WYcAJgBWAGYVt34FhAArEthhPEKQGmEECgBPWQUVepJNIA)

You can work around this by assigning the value you are testing to a temporary variable, and then perform type narrowing on that variable, rather than accessing the property directly twice:

```
const bar = Symbol('bar');

class Foo {
    [bar]: string | undefined;
}

function getBarLength(f: Foo) {
    const prop = f[bar];
    if (prop === undefined) {
        throw new Error('Expected bar to be defined');
    }
    return prop.length; // No error
}
```

[Playground Link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4wLwwMoE8C2cQA2AFAOSJIkCUA3AFC3AEIQQwBiIIMA3rTPzADa5ALoAuGNCQBLMAHMYAHxgBXMABMApgDNZm9XQC%209bWuBRp4GHM1QAQsgAym%20VAAWRbRI4hKPPgKgkLAADkggIWgw2sLIInQCMNLaMERhEWio6GpaumD6fryJie7hAO4w%20RUAokjhSKTVAB4hmub68MgwUFxwmjC5eupUCQLGiUi2KkhgMOkhAHQELnLu1DAA9BswAHJcmnUgSLTGQA)